# Struts2 (version 2.5.33) restricts the limit of query string parameters

Tags: ajax, struts2, httprequest

I have an application that sends query string of approx. 100000 of characters - (500 Array Object converted to String and attached to url). It was working fine when the struts version was 2.5.30 but after I upgrade this version to 2.5.33 I am unable to send query string of 100000 of characters.  I am able to send only 50000 characters.

I use POST method to send the request.

How can I increase the query string of parameters limit to 20000000 in struts?

I don't want to downgrade to 2.5.30 as it is not safe when uploading a files.

Comment: It is not appropriate to send big data in the query string and it also not appropriate to to send it at whole. However, you can send it by parts. But it is not related to your problem.

Comment: Could you explain why you want such a big payload in a query string? Since it is a POST method, can you send it in the body instead?